# Are there further "sandwich"-Carmichael-numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

A Carmichael number $N$ has the property that for every $a$ coprime to $N$, the equation $a^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$ holds, although $N$ is composite.

A number $N$ is a Carmichael number, if $N$ is odd and squarefree, has at least $3$ distinct prime factors and for every prime $p$ dividing $N$, we have $p-1|N-1$.

The Carmichael number $$N=656601=3\cdot 11\cdot 101\cdot 197$$ has the property that both $N-2$ and $N+2$ are prime, it is "sandwiched" by $2$ primes, we could call it a "sandwich"-Carmichael-number.

> Are there any further Carmichael-number "sandwiched" by two primes in this way ?

It is clear that such a number $N$ must be divisble by $3$ , because the smallest Carmichael number is $561$ and if $N$ is not divisible by $3$, $N-2$ or $N+2$ is divisble by $3$. I am currently searching another example, there is none for $N\le 1.6\cdot 10^9$

Comment: Can anyone guess the reason for this downvote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the list of Carmichael numbers up to $10^{16}$ from Pinch, I found with my MPArith routines the following "sandwiched" Carmichael number (in 54sec)

$$656601,
25536531021,
8829751133841,
60561233400921,
79934093254401,
352609909731201,
598438077923841,
976515437206401,
2122162714918401,
2789066007968241,
3767175573114801,
7881891474971361$$

The list contains $246683$ Carmichael numbers and is available from
http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/math/funet/misc/RichardPinch/Carmichael/carmichael-16.gz

Comment: Seeing this, it somehow seems likely there are infinitely many of these guys.

Comment: Might be worth adding to the OEIS.